# Finding optimal path on 2d area with specific rules

Tags: java, arrays, math

I have a 2d grid of integers with dimensions (n1xn2):

```
1 4 3
3 5 7
2 6 4
```

The goal is to find the path from left to right that has the highest sum. For example, in this case the sum would be `3 + 6 + 7 = 16`. The path can only move east and only to neighbors of itself (i.e. you could not jump from 2 to 4 because 4 is more than one unit away).

My question is what methods can I find and store every possible path on a user given grid knowing its dimensions? Is it conducive to store the entire grid in a 2D array of `int[rows][cols]` or `int[cols][rows]`? I assume this would be done most simply in a recursive way.

I know there are similar questions but I was unable to formulate a working solution from them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would make a good Code Golf question.

Comment: What do you like us to do? I can only say it doesn't matter if you use `int[rows][cols]` or vice versa if you address them right.

Comment: Recursion and efficiency have nothing to do with whether or not you store the matrix or its transpose.

Comment: Almost https://projecteuler.net/problem=81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt I made, it works but it's in python.
The matrix is stored per column , the basic idea was to create a list of all possible paths across the matrix from left to right and then at the end find the path with the max value.

For each item , grab the list of possible sub-paths and append the current item. 
The sub-paths are generated recursively.

I know it's not in Java but the logic's the same, hope this helps.

```
matrix = [[1,3,2],[4,5,6],[3,7,4]]


def findMax(pathList): 
    maxPath = []
    maxVal = 0
    for path in pathList:
        add =  sum(path)
        if add > maxVal:
            maxVal = add
            maxPath = path
    print "Path: " + str(maxPath) + " val: "+str(maxVal)     

def iterateMatrix(args): #initial method
    firstcol = args[0] #pop off first column
    allpaths = []
    for i in range(0,len(firstcol)): 
        childPaths = iterateChildren(args,1) #grab all possible subpaths
        for x in range(0,len(childPaths)):
            allpaths.append([firstcol[i]]+childPaths[x])
    print allpaths
    #built a list of all possible paths from left to right
    #now iterate and calculate the sum
    findMax(allpaths)

def iterateChildren(args,index):#build up a list of possible combinations of columns in the matrix
    paths = []
    if index == (len(args)-1): #if there are no more possible sub-paths to compute
        for i in range(0,len(args[index])):
            paths.append(args[index][i])
        return paths
    else:
        childPaths = iterateChildren(args, index+1)
        for x in range(0,len(args[index])):
            for y in range(0,len(childPaths)):
                paths.append([args[index][x],childPaths[y]])
    return paths

iterateMatrix(matrix)
```

Comment: I honestly don't think I would've thought to do it this way. Clever!

Comment: It was an interesting problem alright :) but  I should say that this method isn't really scalable , it would probably take a long time to compute for larger matrices

Comment: I attempted to implement this solution. The problem is, since Java is statically typed, you can't have an array that contains multiple types (like the paths array in your iterateChildren method, which generates arrays that could contain int values and int[] values like [3, [4,5]]). Any idea on how I could get around this?

Comment: You can have an arraylist containing an arraylist of integers , messy , but its still the same construct , ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Comment: In this case iterateChildren returns an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>, correct? How then would I modify the line just before the return where you are appending the childPaths list? I was trying to use ArrayList<int[]> (clearly to no avail).

Comment: The way I would change that line is to make a new ArrayList<integer> object , put args[index][I] at the front of the list, then use the addAll method to append childPaths[y] to the new list   then add this new created ArrayList to paths

Comment: I've gotten it working now. There is a bug, however. If you use the matrix `matrix = [[1,7,4],[3,2,1],[4,1,8]]` it returns 18, but the correct answer is 17. The path it finds is 7, 3, 8 but moving from 3 to 8 is an illegal move (it is not a direct neighbor).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90114/discussion-between-nick-and-scrineym).

Comment: Hi @Nick I'm actually out at the moment, I'll edit my answer to show a Java version later on, but for the time being to fix the bug I'd say on the last paths.append in iteratechoildren, you need to compare the indexes x and y , I.e if x+1 ==y or x==y or x-1==y , that should check if the item at index x is a neighbour of the item in index y

Answer (score 0):

> what methods can I find and store every possible path on a user given grid

For each possible start point (first entry of each row), make all possible moves right and up/across/down that stay on the board. This may have agood recursive solution.

> `int[rows][cols]` or `int[cols][rows]`

I generally use `int[rows][cols]` because I can picture it in my mind clearly - remember that this means you must access it as `grid[y][x]` which may feel odd to begin with.

Comment: I understand that you have to make all possible moves this way, I still don't understand *how* I would implement it.